# Join, Group By and Aggregate with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, aggregate

I am kinda new to LINQ and I am trying to write the SQL below into a LINQ statement.
It works except for the aggregate part in the SQL version (`COUNT(oec.CourseTitle)`), which I cannot figure out how to do that in LINQ. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**SQL**

```
select 
oec.OnlineEducationCourseId, 
oec.CourseTitle,
COUNT(oec.CourseTitle) as CourseCount
from OnlineEducationRegistration as oer
join OnlineEducationCourse oec on oec.OnlineEducationCourseId = oer.OnlineEducationCourseId
where oer.District='K20'and DateCompleted BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'
group by oec.CourseTitle,oec.OnlineEducationCourseId;
```

**LINQ**

```
var r = (from oer in db.OnlineEducationRegistrations
         join oec in db.OnlineEducationCourses on oer.OnlineEducationCourseId equals
         oec.OnlineEducationCourseId
         where oer.District == districtId && 
               oer.DateCompleted >= start && 
               oer.DateCompleted <= end
               group new {oer, oec} by new {oec.CourseTitle, oec.OnlineEducationCourseId}).ToList();



        foreach (var item in r)
        {
            var courseId = item.Key.OnlineEducationCourseId;
            var courseTitle = item.Key.CourseTitle;
            // aggregate count goes here


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically just

```
var courseCount = item.Count();
```

Or you could add it in a select

```
var r = (from oer in db.OnlineEducationRegistrations
         join oec in db.OnlineEducationCourses on oer.OnlineEducationCourseId equals
         oec.OnlineEducationCourseId
         where oer.District == districtId && 
               oer.DateCompleted >= start && 
               oer.DateCompleted <= end
         group new {oer, oec} by new {oec.CourseTitle, oec.OnlineEducationCourseId} into g
         select new {g.OnlineEducationCourseId, g.CourseTitle, CourseCount = g.Count() }).ToList();



    foreach (var item in r)
    {
        var courseId = item.OnlineEducationCourseId;
        var courseTitle = item.CourseTitle;
        var courseCount = item.CourseCount;
    }
```